# Entering three elements at different points in retrieval/list

Tags: php

I am listing batsmen and i have a page showing a top 50. What i want to do is have three separate points in the list where i can enter three different elements.

I would like to do this after the 10th, 24th, 42nd batsmen. How would i go about doing this with php?

My current code retrieves the batsmen and in my controller it has a take of 50

```
@foreach($batsmen as $bat)
<h2> $bat->name</h2>
<h3> $bat->nationality</h3>
<h3> $bat->highscore</h3>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal PHP you would use an index, and increment the index in your loop. I'm not clear with what your three different elements are, but this should help:

```
<?php
// Here $i is your index
$i = 1;
foreach($batsmen as $bat){
    // When the index reaches 10, 24, and 42 then add the three different elements

    // Anything output here is done every iteration of the loop
    // and before your ads

    if( $i == 10 ){
        echo '<div id="ad1"></div>';
    }

    if( $i == 24 ){
        echo '<div id="ad2"></div>';
    }

    if( $i == 42 ){
        echo '<div id="ad3"></div>';
    }

    // Here we are incrementing the index
    $i++;

    // Anything output here is done every iteration of the loop
    // and after your ads
}
```

Comment: Its three different ads. so it will be three different divs. So by the looks of your code it won't work, or will it?

Comment: This now shows three divs at each point, I need one separate div at each of those points, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Updated to meet your needs. It for sure answers your original question. Hopefully it is good, as I am leaving.